# Rendering word & excel documents in our app using DOCX.js and XLSX.js

Tags: javascript, docx, xlsx

Can we Render word & excel documents in our app using DOCX.js and XLSX.js

Comment: According to the description of the docx.js project, yes.

Comment: What do you mean by render ? What is exactly your question ?

Comment: get access to the file programtically and display it in the app.

Answer (score 0):

According to the project description, you can:

> DOCX.js is a JavaScript library for **converting the data** in base64 DOCX files **into HTML** - and back! Please note that this library is licensed under the Microsoft Office Extensible File License - a license NOT approved by the OSI. While this license is based off of the MS-PL, which is OSI-approved, there are significant differences.